# is it okay to persist all entites with only one persist method that take an object as a parameter?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, stateless-session-bean

Can i do that:

```
>  public void save(Object obj) {
>           try {
>               getHibernateSession().save(obj);
>           } catch (Exception e) {
>           
>               e.printStackTrace();
>           }
>           
>       }
```

pass any entity as a parameter, and be sure that it will always be persisted without any problem?

Comment: Yes, because the entity manager itself is already a DAO facade so you should not wrap the entity manager in another DAO facade.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. And if your code (entity hierarchy, for example) will be well, you will be sure that entities will be persisted into database without any problem. The key moment of your question is right classes structure(hierarchy) and right instructions for hibernate through annotations.

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply. Its gonna save quite a lot of time  in my developping from now on